# Problema con representación de caracteres especiales con php y sencha touch

Tags: php, caracteres, sencha

tengo un archivo .php que se usa como diccionario solamente, tiene una estructura similar a esta:

```php
<?php
$lang=array(
//GENERAL
    'Editar'=>'Editar',
    'Foto'=>'Foto',
    'Roles'=>'Roles',
    'Eliminar'=>'Eliminar',
     'cinturon_negro'=>'Cinturón Negro',
    'Si'=>'Si',
    'No'=>'No',
    'PROPIOS'=>'PROYECTOS PROPIOS',
    'ASIGNADOS'=>'PROYECTOS ASIGNADOS',); ?>
```

estoy trabajando con un framework llamado sencha touch también, bueno... se genera una vista y se hace una consulta a una base de datos, esta base de datos devuelve por ejemplo: 'cinturon_negro' , pero cuándo mando a mostrar eso debería mostrarse Cinturón Negro y no sucede, lo que se muestra es: Cinturï¿½n Negro , cabe destacar que el valor que estoy mostrando no esta viniendo de la Base de Datos, lo que viene es la clave por la que lo busco en el archivo .php . por que sucede esto? la verdad no entiendo que pasa. Que podría ser?

Comment: Prueba envolverlo en en un utf8_decode()  al resultado de la consulta

Comment: Pero es que no es el resultado de la consulta lo que muestro. El resultado de la consulta simplemente es la clave, ejemplo: si devuelve cinturon_negro el valor que muestro sería Cinturón Negro.

Comment: Cuando examinas la respuesta de PHP con Herramientas de Desarrollo del browser ¿se ven bien?.

Comment: No se ve como debería, sale así: Cintur\u00ef\u00bf\u00bdn Negro pero no entiendo por que, ya que lo que tengo en la base de datos es cinturon_negro , Cinturón Negro está es en el archivo .php , es decir, desde la base de datos no viene un valor con Cinturón Negro, no se si me explico bien?

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate que la codificación de tu archivo php coincida con la del tipo de contenido que regresa.

En la mayoría de los editores se puede configurar el tipo de codificación al guardar el archivo, el valor predeterminado suele ser dependiente del sistema operativo, de tal manera que en Windows es 1252 ó latin1, mientras que OS X tiene Mac OS Roman; la recomendación es usar `UTF-8`.

Dicha codificación debe ser la misma que declares en el encabezado http:

`header('Content-Type: application/<tipo>; charset=utf-8');`

Si regresas html, además debe coincidir también con:

`<head><meta charset="utf-8">`

Adicionalmente puedes verificar:

- Con `phinfo()` el valor de `default_charset`.
- Si usas apache, en `httpd.conf` la entrada `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`.

Comment: Estoy en visual studio code y dice que está en utf-8, los encabezados los tengo configurados con utf-8 y también tengo la etiqueta en el head del html, que otra cosa podría ser? No hallo la solución.

Comment: Confirma guardando el php nuevamente, si utilizas otros editores y/o compartes/descargas pudiera ser que la última vez que se guardó no fue en utf-8. Agrego a la respuesta un par de opciones.

Comment: En el archivo PHP me aparecen los caracteres especiales así: � . y la codificación está en un UTF-8 según el VSC, abaja en la parte inferior derecha dice: UTF-8. Lo guarde de nuevo,pero al guardar no hay donde colocar la codificación, simplemente guardé y reemplacé el anterior y no hizo efecto alguno. También revisé el archivo httpd.conf y la entrada AddDefaultCharset no aparece, uso XAMPP.

Comment: Amigo cambié a ISO-8859-1 desde visual studio code y ahora si se muestran los caracteres especiales como: ó, í, etc. No entiendo por que, cuál será la explicación?

Comment: Por la misma causa de tu problema; el archivo está en 8859-1; cambia a utf-8 en VSC haciendo click en la codificación en la barra de estado, corrige los caracteres que se vean mal en el mismo VSC y guarda.

Comment: Si lo cambio a UTF-8 dejan de mostrarse los caracteres especiales, No entiendo por que. Otra cosa, estoy haciendo una consulta a una Base de Datos con PHP y tampoco me muestra los caracteres especiales como debe ser. la Tabla de la BD está codificada en utf-8_spanish_ci , que está pasando ahí?